# How to create a variable size 2D string array by passing variable

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, dynamic

Could anyone give me an sample how to create a 2D char array in C by passing the variable for the array length.

```
//Current program
int i;
int seq_cnt;    
exec sql    
        select count(0)     
        into seq_cnt     
        from    table;    
char tmp1[50][5+1];       
char tmp2[50][5+1];   

for(i=0;i < seq_cnt ; i++){   
     strcpy(tmp1[i],"something");    
     strcpy(tmp2[i],"something");    
}
```

Now what I want is for the array size of `tmp1` and `tmp2`, I want to use the `seq_cnt` to declare the actual size of `tmp1` and `tmp2` instead of hardcode it (50).

like:

```
char tmp1[seq_cnt][5+1];     
char tmp2[seq_cnt][5+1];
```

I'm new to C.

Comment: `char tmp1[seq_cnt][5+1];     
char tmp2[seq_cnt][5+1];` should work if you are using C99+. Or you can resort to dynamically allocating memory using `malloc`. Note: `"something"` won't fit into an array of size `5 + 1`

Comment: @Spikatrix: Depends on the compiler. Some VC version do not support VLAs. Also C11 made VLAs optional. C++ does not know them at all.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use the seq_cnt to declare the actual size of tmp1

Do

```
char (*tmp1)[5+1] = malloc(seq_cnt * sizeof *tmp1);
```

Update on the three different usages of an asterisk `*` in C.

1. Types/Variable definitions

   Here

   ```
   char (*tmp1)[5+1]
   ```

   the asterisk is used to define a pointer, a pointer to a `char[5+1]` array.

   <sup>Please not that the parentheses are mandatory, as `char *tmp[5+1]` would defined an array of 6 pointer to `char`.</sup>
2. Indirection (or de-referencing) operator

   Here

   ```
   sizeof *tmp1
   ```

   the asterisk is used to tell the compiler to not take the size of `tmp1` which would be the size of a pointer, but the size of what `tmp1` points to, namely a `char[5+1]`.

   <sup>Alternatively one could write `sizeof (char[5+1])`. Please note that the parenthesis are not belonging to `sizeof` as it is not a function, but an operator.</sup>
3. Multiplication operator

   Here

   ```
   seq_cnt * sizeof ...
   ```

   the asterisk is used to indicate an ordinary multiplication, namely to calculate the product of `seq_cnt` and the size of something.

So all in all the top statement allocates `seg_cnt` times the bytes a `char[5+1]` needs  and assigns the address of the 1st byte of the chunk allocated to `tmp1`, makes it point to enough memory to hold `seq_cnt` array of `char[5+1]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I want exactly . Could you mind explaining it more ? I am not familiar with malloc . and there is so many * that making me confused.